# How do I get rid of these files?

Tags: command-line, rm, purge, locate

I installed a program, decided I don't want to use it anymore so I got rid of it with:

`sudo apt purge "target_program"`

The program got uninstalled but left behind some leftover files and directories which show up with `locate "target_program"` but can't be found manually via explorer and when I open up the containing directories in the terminal and try to delete them with the `rm` command i get `rm: cannot remove 'target_program': No such file or directory`. None of the files are hidden, I managed to delete 2 directories with `rm -r target_program` and this is what I'm left with:

```
/etc/target_program
/usr/bin/target_program
/usr/bin/target_programapi
/usr/share/target_program
/usr/share/doc/target_program
/usr/share/man/man1/target_program.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/target_program.1.gz
/usr/share/python3/runtime.d/target_program.rtupdate
/var/cache/apt/archives/target_program.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/target_program.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/target_program.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/target_program.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/target_program.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/target_program.prerm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo apt purge <target_program>` not only removes all installed files (`remove`), but also removes systemwide configuration files (typically in `/etc`). That you still see them them in the output of the `locate` command is because that tool works on a cache. Do a `sudo updatedb` and try again: these files will not anymore be found by locate as well.

`purge` will not delete downloaded installation archives. To delete all downloaded ("cached") installation archives, use the command `sudo apt clean`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped! Now I'm only left with `/var/cache/apt/archives/target_program.deb` How do I get rid of this one as well?

Comment: The purge command is not supposed to remove that file. Will add some comments on "purge" and the `.deb` file to the answer

Comment: I tried `sudo apt clean` as well as `sudo apt-get autoclean` but the file still remains

Comment: Please remember to use the updatedb command to make the output of locate reflect your current state.

Comment: My bad! Now it's gone. Appreciate the help!